# Return value if exists in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get data with firstOrFail() to getting data with eloquent laravel. but facing an issue, when i'm trying to fetch the data is not exist then it will return me model exception. How can i make it into return data if the data is exist while return null or "" if the value or field doesn't exist. I tried to add the following but it will lead the page into total blank.

(global.php)

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
    // return Response::make('Not Found', 404);
    return "";
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `firstOrFail`, just use `first`:

```
$model = Model::first();
```

If no model was found, `$model` will be `null`.